# Changing MAC address, through registry does not work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mac-address

i am using visual studio 2010 and Windows XP on a macbook through bootcamp.

I realized that i could not change the MAC address through the registry(through **RegSetValueEx**), if my adapter selected is the one integrated to the laptop, Eg: Broadcom wireless adapter for macbook.However certain values like AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF worked.

However if i plug in a **wireless usb network adapter it worked flawlessly**.My guess is that it is not my code that is having the problem,since i tried other downloaded from the internet and it is the same thing. Can anyone explained why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure you can change the MAC address?

Comment: A MAC address is not something you want to change - it's like the computer's one and only way to get identified on the network besides having an IP, but the MAC allows you to identify the computer regardless of it's IP. It's a bad idea to change the MAC address without any very very good reasoning behind it, as it is something that you can't easily change for a purpose.

Comment: @Vjo what do you mean? I have no problems changing the mac address on a usb wireless adapter.

Comment: I have been also trying to change the MAC address of the wireless adapter of my MacBook in Mac OS X. I have noticed that the same command works in some cases but not in others. I have no idea why it fails when it fails or why it works when it works (and I would really like to know!), but I am also pretty sure that it's not a problem with your code.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change your computer's MAC address?

Comment: @Cody Gray It is a school project meant to show the weakness of MAC filtering.

Comment: @cefstat i can change my mac address in osx through `sudo ifconfig [adapter_name] ether [mac_address]` but i must not be connected to any network first

Comment: @cftmon Yes, I'm well aware that I must not be connected to any network first (`airport -z` is your friend). But there was just one situation where it was impossible to change the MAC address, although (I think) I was doing everything correctly. Never found out what the reason was and never had the chance to try again in the same situation. BTW, yes, MAC filtering is an extremely weak protection for wireless networks.

Comment: Not all devices allow changing the MAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your answer I managed to solve the problem. AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF-GG works because of a big luck. The idea is that Windows 7 imposes some restrictions, as you can se on the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing . So, "Under Windows 7, the possible range of spoofed addresses that can be set is limited for wireless and wired network adapters. To be used by Windows 7, a spoofed MAC address should have 0 as a least significant bit (unicast) and 1 as a second least significant bit (locally administered) in the second nibble. Thus possible values for the second nibble are limited to 2, 6, A and E." The two specified bits, as I could see from the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address correspond to the second character of the MAC address, thus, any address that have the second character 2,6,A, or E works. No other one could.

T

Answer (score 0):

The custom MAC address may need to conform to the following format:

- x2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
- x6-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
- xA-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
- xE-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx

`x` can be any number from 0 to F.

---

The reason is as follows:

1. [MAC address - I/G bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Unicast_vs._multicast_(I/G_bit))

   The least significant bit of an MAC address's first octet is referred to as the I/G (Individual/Group) bit.

   - 0: Unicast MAC Address
   - 1: Multicast MAC Address

   The I/G bit of a custom mac address needs to be set to 0.
2. [MAC address - U/L bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Universal_vs._local_(U/L_bit))

   the second-least-significant bit of an MAC address's first octet is referred to as the U/L (Universal/Local) bit.

   - 0: Universally Administered MAC Address
   - 1: Locally Administered MAC Address

   The U/L bit of a custom mac address needs to be set to 1.